# "Топлес" - літературне слово?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники

Як і в попередньому дописі, знову запитую про лексему "топлес", однак цікавить вже чи це літературне слово.У [Словнику іншомовних соціокультурних термінів](http://slovopedia.org.ua/39/53410/260975.html) воно наявне:

> **ТОПЛЕС** (від англ. topless - без верха) без верхньої частини одежі, з відкритими грудьми (про конкурсанток, моделей тощо).

Але якщо звернутись за підтвердженням в академічні [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/toples), [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=51819&page=1648), то його там немає.

Отож **"топлес"** - літературне слово?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так, це слово є літературним, просто запозиченим (в [СУМі в 11 т.](http://sum.in.ua/) його немає, очевидно, через те, що цей словник видавався в 1970-1980-хх рр., і це слово не було поширеним),  а в [СУМі в 20-х т.](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=1&page=0)  ще слів на **т** немає).
У [Великому тлумачному словнику сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005.](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/179594/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81) без  будь-яких позначок знаходимо це слово:

> **топлес**
>
> невідм.
>   1) Який оголює груди (про жіночий одяг).
>   2) Одягнута в сукню без ліфа.

Також це слово наявне в вищенаведеному Вами словнику. Тому, можна стверджувати, що це слово є **нормативним**.